# MYSQL mysqldump error is occurring in mac os shell script running with XAMPP

Tags: mysql, macos, shell, xampp

I'm trying to run the following script through the command line on my mac mojave 10.14.3 running xampp 7.2.12-0:

```
    #!/bin/sh
PATH=/usr/local/bin:~/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Application/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin

#----------------------------------------------------
# a simple mysql database backup script.
# version 2, updated March 26, 2011.
# copyright 2011 alvin alexander, http://devdaily.com
#----------------------------------------------------
# This work is licensed under a Creative Commons
# Attribution-ShareAlike 3.0 Unported License;
# see http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/
# for more information.
#----------------------------------------------------

# (1) set up all the mysqldump variables
database="mybackup"
backupdir="."
backupuser="root"
day=`date +%u`
mkdir -p $backupdir/$day
 echo -n "Exporting $database..."
 mysqldump --opt --user=$backupuser --all-databases > ./$day/$database.sql
 echo -n "compressing..."
 gzip ./$day/$database.sql
 echo "done"
```

Executing this script generates the following command line error:

```
backup1.sh: line 22: mysqldump: No such file or directory
```

When I run the mysqldump command directly, it is executed properly.  Does anyone have any thoughts on what I'm doing incorrectly?

The permissioning follows:

```
drwxrwxrwx+ 8 777       admin       256 Mar 16 08:44 .
drwxrwxrwx  4 777       admin       128 Mar 14 22:13 ..
-rw-r--r--@ 1 myLaptop  admin      6148 Mar 15 22:17 .DS_Store
drwxr-xr-x  7 myLaptop  admin       224 Mar 16 08:54 5
drwxr-xr-x  5 myLaptop  admin       160 Mar 16 09:18 6
-rwxr-xr-x@ 1 myLaptop  admin      1348 Mar 15 18:22 backup.sh
-rwxrwxrwx@ 1 myLaptop  admin       878 Mar 16 09:18 backup1.sh
```

Any help, much appreciated!!

Comment: it seems a path problem... Are you sure `./$day/$database.sql` with `day=date +%u` resolves correctly? particularly why are you using the character ` in the definition of day?

Comment: i removed $day, still generating the same error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I delete

```
PATH=/usr/local/bin:~/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Application/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin
```

then the script works.

Go figure?

Comment: Try running just that line in a new script, maybe there is an error